# Bash Script: How to use variables from list

Tags: bash, shell, unix, loops, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will report back the last time a file was updated in a folder. The folders are created everyday Example: /home/user/todaysdate. Inside todaysdate folder exsist that are created when somethng is created. So for example we will have fol1 fol2 fol3. I am trying to get a script to login to each folder and display the time of the last file created.

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=`date +%Y%m%d`
ssh -q server "cd /home/user/$folder/ ; bash -c "ls -la | uniq" > list.txt
```

This will create a list of the different folders that were made. Now I need to ssh into each folder  which is where I am stuck.
The output of the list.txt will be:
    fol1 fol2 fol3

```
ssh -q server "bash -c \"ls -ltr /home/user/$folder/<Need List Variable Here> | tail -1\"" awk '{print $8}
```

The above command gives me my time. I believe I need a while loop to ssh into the server and into the variables created in list.txt but I can't get a working on. Any help?

Comment: disregard fixed it using a for loop. `for LINE in $(cat list.txt)
 do`

Answer (score 1):

If list.txt is space separated (eg "fol1 fol2 fol3") try a bash for/in loop:

```
for folder in $(cat list.txt);
do
    echo $folder;
done
```

If list.txt is newline separated then try a bash while loop:

```
cat list.txt | while read folder;
do
    echo $folder;
done
```

See this page for more information about bash loops.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: Unfortunately, reading from a file or from $(ls) are both fraught with perils.  Filenames can have special characters that really hose you.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs